# Meteor - publish a collection's documents based on another collection's data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm building an app (using `Meteor`) in which users can receive tasks and get points. The app has a leaderboard showing the points & ranks of the current user and 2 more users below and above him in the leaderboard. Here's an example:

LEADERBOARD
rank....user...................points
3.........user A...............100
4.........user B...............80
**5.........user C...............60**  (current user)
6.........user D...............40
7.........user E...............15

Let's say I want to retrieve the leaderboard of *this month*, here are the steps:
- Fetch **user C** document in `Meteor.users` collection
- Fetch the done tasks of **user C** in *this month*
- Sum the points of **user C's tasks** to get his points
- Base on **user C's points**, fetch two users below him (has less points) and above him (has more points) => **HOW TO DO THIS ?**
- Return 5 users to the client

I'm stuck at step 4 and looking forward to your suggestions. Thanks !

Comment: Check out the following Mongo Operators in combination: `$or`, `$gt` and `$lt` which should make you be able to create the query you described

Answer (score 0):

- Fetch user C document in Meteor.users collection :

  ```
  let userC = Meteor.users.findOne(username : 'userC');
  ```
- Fetch the done tasks of user C in this month :

  ```
   let tasksUserC = Tasks.find({userId : userC._id}).fetch()
  ```

(assuming your tasks have a userId field - can be the same with username if uniques username)

- Sum the points of user C's tasks to get his points

  ```
   let userCPoints = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < tasksUserC.length; i++) {
          userCPoints += tasksUserC[i].point;
       }
  ```
- Base on user C's points, fetch two users below him (has less points) and above him (has more points) => HOW TO DO THIS ?

  ```
  let allUsers = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
  allUsers.sort((a,b) => { return a.points - b.points });
  let indexOfUserC = allUsers.indexOf(userC);
  let fiveNeededUsers = allUsers[indexOfUserC - 2; indexOfUserC + 2];
  ```
- Return 5 users to the client:

  ```
  return fiveNeededUsers;
  ```

Didn't try it but should do the trick if you adapt with the fields in your databse.